# Limit of random variables indipendent from a fixed sigma algebra.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Let $(X_n)_{ n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables that converges (in probability) to a random variable $X$. Let's suppose that each $X_n$ is independent from a fixed sigma-algebra $F$, i.e. $\sigma(X_n)$ is independent from $F$ for each $n$.

Is it always true that $X$ is independent from $F$?

My apologies in advance: I am aware that this should be an easy question but I have not so much familiarity with the field of Probability and I am doing my best for improve.

Any hint will be very welcome!
(I bet there's some property from measure theory that I am missing :)
Cheers

Comment: Convergence in probability implies convergence on a subsequence almost surely hence you are done if you know that almost sure convergence preserves independence from a given sigma-algebra. Do you?

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Actually, I didn't know that almost surely convergence preserves independence. Do you mind proving it or maybe giving some reference?

Comment: The idea is rather that *you* try to provide a proof (the obvious idea works).

Comment: Sure! I am trying but something is going wrong. The way that I am following is: let $G$ be the sigma algebra generates by all the $X_n$. Then, every $X_n$ is measurable according to this sigma algebra, consequently the same must be for its limit. Being this sigma algebra independent from $F$, we are done. I am 100% sure it works with (strong) convergence...is it still true with almost sure one?

Comment: (in the previous comment I meant: "consequently the same must be for its limit in the pointwise convergence". Question: is it still true for the weaker almost surely convergence?)

Comment: @user233650: I don't think that it will work for sure convergence. Note that if $X_n, X_m$ are independent of $F$, it does not follow in general that $(X_n, X_m)$ is independent of $F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $B$ is an event in $F$ and $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is bounded and continuous, then $\Bbb E[1_Bg(X)]=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bbb E[1_Bg(X_n)]$. [For this you need to know that convergence in probability is preserved by composition with continuous functions.]